# Passing Get value to different jquery file

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm newbie at Jquery. I stacked to passing php $_GET['myvalue'] to my jquery file.

I struggled very much but I cannot find solution.

I have different one php file and one jquery file. I call my php file like

```
myphpfile.php?myvalue=testvalue
```

Then I want to receive myvalue's value to my jquery file. I tried document.getElementById but It doesnt work.

For any helping Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your jQuery File:

First create a function to parse the parameters in the URL:

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

Then you call the function:

```
var myUrlParameters = getUrlVars();
```

Then you can access them with:

```
var myParameter = myUrlParameters['myParameter'];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the `$_GET['myvalue']` value in your Javascript you can echo it out straight into it.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   // Your code 
   // The var you want to assign it to 
   var value = '<?php echo $_GET['myvalue'];?>'
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read more about jQuery and Javascript...

You might want to add the variable you want in an HTML element, for example:

PHP

```
<?php
    $myValue = $_GET["myvalue"];
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="'.$myValue.'" id="myElement" />';
?>
```

At jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($('#myElement'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the `$_GET['myvalue']` value in your script but using only Javascript.

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```